# WIX reuse installer functionality

Tags: wix, components, reusability

**Is there a way to reuse functionality of WIX installler without copy-pasting the code?**

Reusing UI or other functionality that doesn't have components is simple.

But, for example, creating new site requires few components (with conditions for IIS 6 and IIS 7), enabling ASP.NET 4, enabling required windows features, etc. I want this functionality to be reused in multiple installers - all of them does more or less the same for different products.

But the problem is Component GUIDs - if I create wixlib with this functionality, all applications get components with same GUID and it will cause conflict problems.

The only thing I could think of for now is xml transformations (XDT or XSLT) of the wxs file with reusing functionality.

Does anybody have better ideas?

Comment: May be this will help http://www.joyofsetup.com/2009/12/31/simplifying-wix-component-authoring/

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work with site components. And as I understand it generates GUID based on ID. So it is again possible that few components in different products have the same GUID

Answer (score 2):

If you truly are installing the same stuff the Component Guid *should* be the same for all those Components. If you have a file that lives in the Components (a much better KeyPath than the Directory) the auto-guid will generate unique Guids when installed to different locations. Finally, you could use binder variables, !(wix.Var), to replace the Guids at bind time. I would consider the former two options first.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Rob. Probably I need to read more about auto GUIDs - they really might have helped with most of functionality I have. The components I install for different products are not the same, but they do same things (for example, the block to install a web site - includes 6 components and a lot of other stuff and is reused in every site I install). The same with saving user-input-properties to registry, including Remember property pattern (special thank to you for that =) ). My other objective was to make installer independent on any changes in product (renames, file moves, ...)

Comment: I wasn't confident in how autoproperties will work and how to test if they work properly at that time.
So I couldn't find anything better than hand-written util for WIX files transformations. It replaces wildcards in WIX file (custom command-line properties and transform functions: {GuidHash({ProductName}-AC8390F...)}). I already have about 20 templates and the approach works perfectly for about half a year in 6 installers. That's my current solution of a problem (it was only my second installer when I invented it, so it probably could be done better). In future I'll use your recommendations